# redirecting users to sub-sites based on their country ip

Tags: redirect, woocommerce, geolocation, ip, subdomain

I am trying to redirect users to a sub-Domain based on their country and restrict access to another country's version of the site. its a woo-commerce website and i don't want use plugins i want a free solution if there any i want someone can explain how to do that is files is there a code or something like that my idea is redirect visitor from mywebsite.com to Egypt.mywebsite.com if they visit from Egypt my hosting is site ground and it doesn't have GeoIP , i access to cloudflare and they provide a link but i dont know how to use it

Get IP Geolocation setting

```
GET https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/117889afac45e54260dc78eb9de9b26b/settings/ip_geolocation
```

Change IP Geolocation setting

```
PATCH https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/117889afac45e54260dc78eb9de9b26b/settings/ip_geolocation
```